# Why stealthy Tensorflow upgrade to 2.9.1 breaks Google Colab Jupyter notebooks that use GPU but not CPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

Sometime in the last three days, an upgrade to TensorFlow on Google colab was made from 2.8.x to 2.9.1. This upgrade broke all of my current research notebooks including a minimal MNIST example I have included. A thorough review of the release notes does not show that any of the packages that I am using in Keras or TensorFlow were changed.

Further work on this error revealed it only occurs when the Colab runtime includes a GPU. It works fine on a Colab CPU or TPU.
Here is a 34 line example that reproduces the error:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    import keras
    
    # the data, split between train and test sets
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
    
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
    x_test  = x_test.reshape ( x_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
    input_shape = (28, 28, 1)
    
    x_train  = x_train.astype('float32')
    x_test   = x_test.astype('float32')
    x_train /= 255
    x_test  /= 255
    
    # convert class vectors to binary class matrices
    y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
    y_test  = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test , 10)
    
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    
    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=100, epochs=1, verbose=1, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
    score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
    print('Test loss:', score[0], 'Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

I have included a trace of the errors below.

When I downgrade back to tensorflow 2.8.2 the error disappears and all my collab notebooks work normally.

To keep using a GPU, the current workaround, which adds 86 seconds per run is:

```
    !pip install tensorflow==2.8.2
    import tensorflow as tf
    print(tf.__version__)
```

- Error Log when GPU is included in runtime configuration:

```
Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz
11490434/11490434 [==============================] - 0s 0us/step
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
[<ipython-input-1-05f207168698>](https://localhost:8080/#) in <module>
     31               metrics=['accuracy'])
     32 
---> 33 model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=100, epochs=1, verbose=1, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
     34 score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
     35 print('Test loss:', score[0], 'Test accuracy:', score[1])

1 frames
[/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57     if name is not None:

UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:

    [...]

Node: 'sequential/conv2d/Conv2D'
DNN library is not found.
     [[{{node sequential/conv2d/Conv2D}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_865]
```

Answer (score 1):

Google Colab has "solved" the issue by downgrading the default version of Tensorflow.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

Now outputs 2.8.2 for both GPU and CPU runtime.

And indeed now the code that you posted does not produces errors anymore.