# DNN library is not found. (Google Colab)

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, cudnn

I'm working on a ML project using Google Colab and Tensorflow to train a CNN, starting from the EfficientNetV2M model.
It used to work just fine until two days ago, when starting the training:

```
train = model.fit(X, y, epochs=save_every_n_epochs, batch_size=16, verbose=1)
```

gave the following error:

```
UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-1b2fb9765100> in <module>
     70     print(f"Training the model for {save_every_n_epochs} epochs")
     71 
---> 72     train = model.fit(X, y, epochs=save_every_n_epochs, batch_size=16, verbose=1)
     73     print("Model trained")
     74 

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57     if name is not None:

UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sequential/efficientnetv2-m/stem_conv/Conv2D' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 612, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1786, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 758, in _run_callback
      ret = callback()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1233, in inner
      self.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1147, in run
      yielded = self.gen.send(value)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 365, in process_one
      yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 268, in dispatch_shell
      yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 545, in execute_request
      user_expressions, allow_stdin,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 306, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 536, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2855, in run_cell
      raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 68, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3058, in run_cell_async
      interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3249, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-5-1b2fb9765100>", line 72, in <module>
      train = model.fit(X, y, epochs=save_every_n_epochs, batch_size=16, verbose=1)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1409, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1040, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1030, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 889, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 490, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1014, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 374, in call
      return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 459, in call
      inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 596, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 490, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1014, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 459, in call
      inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 596, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1014, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional/base_conv.py", line 250, in call
      outputs = self.convolution_op(inputs, self.kernel)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional/base_conv.py", line 232, in convolution_op
      name=self.__class__.__name__)
Node: 'sequential/efficientnetv2-m/stem_conv/Conv2D'
DNN library is not found.
     [[{{node sequential/efficientnetv2-m/stem_conv/Conv2D}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_45723]
```

I wasn't able to train any model since then, always getting this error, also when loading previously stored models.
I am able to train when i use an environment without GPU, but it is obviously too slow.
I've also tried to change the TF version as suggested in other topics, without any success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/10590

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73397368/why-stealthy-tensorflow-upgrade-to-2-9-1-breaks-google-colab-jupyter-notebooks-t) from a few hours ago. Apparently this is a problem related to the latest Tensoflow update introduced in Colab (Tensorflow 2.9.1).

As a quick fix you could downgrade Tensorflow. However only downgrading to tf 2.8, as suggested in the linked question wasn't enough to fix the problem in my case.

Try [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/10590):

```
!pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu

!pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.8
!apt install --allow-change-held-packages libcudnn8=8.1.0.77-1+cuda11.2
```

Also make sure to restart the runtime if it asks you to do so.

Comment: In my case, the issue was solved by running this lines:
`!pip install tensorflow-text==2.8.1`
`!pip install tf-models-official==2.8`
`!pip install tensorflow==2.8`
`!apt install --allow-change-held-packages libcudnn8=8.1.0.77-1+cuda11.2`
Google Colab was using tensorflow 2.10